# How do I make each word in a string a variable with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, variables

How do I make each word a separate variable if the string contains 3 words?  I searched and searched but I have found now tutorial on how to do this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In general with `explode` or `preg_split`, which make an *array* of words. But you need to nail down the formal definition of "word" first.

Comment: str_word_count() with the format argument of 1 is another option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP's `explode` should be what you are looking for.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
$pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
$pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
```

Comment: Little note: If you want to put every single word into a different variable, use `list($variable1, $var2, $var3, ...)` instead of `$pieces`.

Comment: But say my string is from a user input.  Say the string is:

Comment: $input = "ipod touch 5th gen";

Comment: how do i put each word into its own variable.

Comment: `$var1 = $pieces[0]; $var2 = $pieces[1]; ... ` - `$pieces[0]` is the first word, `$pieces[1]` is the second and so on

Answer (score 1):

Look up the [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the words are separated by space:

```
$words = explode(' ', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `list()` if you want each word in its own variable:

`list($var1, $var2, $var3) = explode(' ', $string);`

You could possibly use `extract()` if the number of variables isn't known. Example:

`extract(explode(' ', $string), EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "var");`

If `$string` has four words, they'd end up in `$var_0`, `$var_1`, `$var_2`, `$var_3`. I can't really think of a good reason why one would write such code though.